# My server is up. Now where do I go from here?

Tags: server

I finally got my server up and when I goto local host in a browser i get the "It works!" page.

That's wonderful!

I have my web page put together on my windows7 machine as an HTML/CSS document.

question:

How do I get it over and into my server to be displayed for all the world to see?  I mean, I get it about files and stuff. but I'm not sure of the procedure to cause all this to happen in my Ubuntu box?

Go easy on me folks! I'm a noob at this. But I am clever so just throw me a clue of "where to go" "what to see" and "what to do" and stuff.

Comment: Oh boy, there is so much that you need to learn. One post won't even help you to get an idea of the gigantic world that web development is. Anyway, good luck on the travel! :)

Comment: You can start with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions to transfer your web content to your Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get it over and into my server to be displayed for all the world to see?

As your question has 2 parts, I will try to answer them both. Firstly, the "**How do I get it over**" part. You just need to install ssh server program on your ubuntu box and then ssh from your windows 7 by using [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Putty is better for administrating your ubuntu server, but to transfer files [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is better with a nice GUI and drag&drop operation. It's basically windows version of linux program called 'scp' (Secure CoPy). Either way, you will need ssh.

To install ssh, execute the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And to be able to open localhost on your browser, you need to install apache, or any other software for that matter.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Now, you can have the HTML/CSS documents on the ubuntu server. And you can view the "It works!" page on localhost with browser.

"**To be displayed for all the world to see?**" As for this part of the question, I can only give you a brief guide, as I don't have experience on web development. You will need to buy a domain name (or get a free one), and hosting space (or you can use your ubuntu box as server). Here's a basic tutorial from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-launch-your-site-on-a-new-ubuntu-12-04-server-with-lamp-sftp-and-dns). You can get more information by searching on google.

Comment: Magnificent!!!  Thanks...now i'm off to absorb that info!  cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You install [SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html).

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Then you use it for administering the server from your Windows box (one popular SSH client is [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/)), as well as for transferring files to and from via SFTP (*not* FTP). One SFTP client that I have used is [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), there are many others.

Comment: Thank you....I love to chomp and chew info like a cow chewing cud!